# C - using fork() and exec() twice

Tags: c, linux

I have the following code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char    *program;
    char     stringa[1000] = "";
    int num = 123;
    char snum[10];

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: mon fileName\n where fileName is an executable file.\n");
        exit(-1);
    } else {
        program = argv[1];
        sprintf(stringa, "./%s", program);

        pid_t pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0 ) {
            perror("fork failed."); 
            exit(1); }

        else if (pid == 0) {
            char* args[] = {stringa, NULL};
            execv(args[0], args);
        }
        else {

            char procmon_str[] = "./procmon";
            num = pid;
            sprintf(snum, "%d",num);
            pid_t pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 == 0) {
                char* args2[] = {procmon_str, snum, NULL};
                execv(args2[0], args2); }
            else {

                printf("PID of child is %s", snum);
                int parent_pid = getpid(); 
                printf("PID of parent is %d", parent_pid);}

        }}
    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

The name of this program is `myProgram`. The argument I provide in the shell is:

```
./myProgram calc
```

`calc` is another program I want to launch using `myProgram`.
`myProgram` then executes `calc`, takes its `PID` and passes that `PID` to another program called `procmon` that does something with it; that's why I need to fork twice.
However, when I run the code above, I get:

`procmon: cannot open /proc/6225/stat, the monitored process is not running anymore`.

How can I fix this?

**What does `calc` do?**
It goes into a `for` loop, increments an `int` variable and goes to sleep for 3 seconds and repeat that 10 times. So it should run for about 30 seconds.

**What does `procmon` do?**
`procmon` simply receives a `PID` of a process as an argument and displays the corresponding `/proc/PID/stat` file. It works perfectly when you run it by itself.

Comment: What does `calc` do? Maybe it finished running quickly, before `procmon` looked for it.

Comment: It goes into a `for` loop, increments an `int` variable and goes to sleep for 3 seconds and repeat that 10 times. So it should run for about 30 seconds.

Comment: your error seems to be displayed by `procmon`, so that's where you should be looking for the error.

Comment: If you do `ps -p 6225`, do you see the `calc` process running?

Comment: `procmon` simply receives a `PID` of a process as an argument and displays the corresponding `/proc/PID/stat` file. It works perfectly when you run it by itself.

Comment: @kaylum i just did.
@Barmar if i do that while getting the `Monitoring: /proc/PID/stats` window in the shell, it shows the process actually runs. If i do that after getting the error mentioned above, it doesn't run. So i assume, like you said, that maybe it finishes running before `procmon` looked at it. However, it runs for 30 seconds, that's not "quickly". Any idea on how i can fix this?

Comment: You should probably print an error message and definitely not blithely continue after `execv()`.  The function only ever returns if it fails.  You should normally exit with an appropriate error status.

Comment: Please keep the Pico-style code layout for Pico.  In C, use either 1TBS (One True Brace Style) or Allman — see Wikipedia on [Indent Style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I never continue after `execv()`, it goes straight to the next case of the `if` statement.

Comment: Actually, it goes to the `wait(NULL);`.  However, you should be reporting an error — you need to know when commands fail to execute.  And you should exit with an error status — it is very seldom that you should treat failure to execute a program as 'success'.  This is doubly the case when you're having problems with your code, though it applies to production-ready code too.

Comment: Where is the executable for `calc`?  Is it in the same directory as where you're running this program?  Can you modify `calc` so it reports its presence, for example by printing a message to standard output and flushing standard output?  That way, you'll know when it is running.  You could have it report when it is about to finish too.

Comment: Yeah you're right i'll make sure to use that error checking in future projects. And yes, it's in the same directory.

Comment: You can read what i replied to Barmar earlier - `calc` definitely runs, i checked. But it might be the case that it finishes before `prcomon` reaches it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133386/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-gambit20088).

Comment: Only as to dig in the wound, but have you checked the possibility of failing `exec(2)` call?  Nothing in the code seems you are checking for bad `exec(2)` call, and this makes your subprocesses not last 30s, but just exit (at least this is what you have in the exposed code)

Answer (score 5):

You have a race condition. You have no guarantee that the first `fork()` actually even returns to your parent process before the calc child process finishes executing and exits. You need to synchronize the execution of your processes.

**ETA suggestions on where to block and signal**

```
if (pid == 0) 
{
    // block here waiting for the go-ahead from parent
    char* args[] = { stringa, NULL };
    execv( args[ 0 ], args );
}

......

else
{
    // signal calc child here 
    printf( "PID of child is %s", snum );
    int parent_pid = getpid();
    printf( "PID of parent is %d", parent_pid );
}
```

Learning how to block and signal via interprocess communication is left as an exercise for the questioner.

Comment: I'm not to sure on how to do that.. any code edit suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Didn't notice at first...

Your main process is creating two child processes, proc and prcmon.
Your problem is that due to race conditions and schedualling - calc finishes first, so what you want to do is to force calc to wait for its sibling process. You can only wait() on a process that you created... So this way you can't make calc wait for prcmon to finish.

**BUT**

You can implement some mechanism to make parent process wait on its children and then via pipe pass the return data to other child process. In your case I am not sure. You want in prcmon to get the PID of calc and display it ? I don't know if that is possible as once calc is done, its descriptor is erased and does no longer exist.

A solution to your problem is to make calc do heavy calculation as you only need it alive and not its return value.

Comment: Since `calc` is described as running for 30 seconds, it is improbable that `procmon` cannot run before `calc` completes.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, in that case, procmon might start before calc is being called, and finish before child process execv to calc func

Comment: The process might not be `calc` when `procmon` starts, but the process most probably exists.  It would be an odd system where `fork()` returned to the parent before the process description for the child was not fully available.  After all, the parent is told what the child's PID is, and all `procmon` needs is that the PID exists in the system.

Comment: no race condition in `fork`/`wait` calls.  Sorry but if the child process finishes before the parent has been able to make a `wait` call, the child process will become a _zombie_ process, just waiting the parent to `wait` for it.  This is true since unix v1 (which was not released) and you are not telling the right thing.

Comment: @LuisColorado 
Read my answer again.
What I meant is that they race for CPU time and the process he wishes to remain active finishes first.

A process becomes zombie if it finishes before its parent has waited on it, I know that.
That is not the case, as he needs  the process to be in a `running state`.

Answer (score 0):

So without noticing, my program provided the right output.
My program is called `myProgram` and it is launched like this:

```
./myProgram calc
```

Where `calc` is a program that runs for 30 seconds doing some basic math operations, nothing too crazy.
Then, another process, `procmon` is launched. `procmon` takes the `PID` of `calc` and prints the file:

```
/proc/calc-PID/stat
```

Which is exactly what happened. I received that file to my shell, which means that both `calc` and `procmon` ran successfully. 
For some reason i thought i was supposed to get a new file in the system after running this program, so i didn't even pay much attention to what was happening in the shell.

I'm truly sorry for any confusion it may have caused to some people, i will definitely keep in mind to check my problem 1,000 more times before asking.

I also extremely appreciate everyone's help and support, it's great to be a part of this community!